# What is the "natural rate of interest" vs. "money interest rate"?

Tags: interest-rate, money, history-economic-thought, history

What exactly is the distinction that Knut Wicksell made in his *[Interest & Prices](https://mises.org/library/interest-and-prices)* between

- "natural rate of interest" or "natural interest" ("*der natürliche
  Kapital zins*")

and the

- "money rate of interest"?